# Object to SQL and SQL to Object

Tags: java, sql

I was wondering if there was any way to create a data object from a sql query and the opposite.

Example : 
Here is the object :

```
public class DataObject {
int id;
String name;
}
```

Is there any way to do something like :

```
DataObject[] dataObjects = methodXX("SELECT id, name from XXTABLEXX");
```

And by the opposite I mean for example create DataObject, set some value, and insert/update it directly into the database.

Hope it doesn't seem too strange.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for ORM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) framework.

for example hibernate (http://www.hibernate.org/).

Comment: Thank, I looked at the documentation, but I was wondering if hibernate can be used by a basic java app (no servlet, no tomcat etc)

Comment: of course. hibernate is just responsible for O-R mapping, no matter which kind of application you are writing. It sits between datastore and your Pojos (Entities)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

For Java, check out the [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) framework.